# Using images as input field in get method

Tags: html, css, methods, get

I'm trying to do this:

- Page 1 contains a list of movieposters and titles, loaded from a
  database. These images are links, to page 2.
- Page 2 needs to load more information based on which poster the user
  clicks on on page 1. Every movie has an unique ID, which I use to
  load the poster with at page 1 and that I need to use to load the
  rest of the info on page 2.

It's that ID that I need to give to page 2 when the user clicks on the image.

I tried using a get method and using the image as an input field, but that only gave the button the name of the hmtl to load the image.
I also can't figure out a way to get it as a $_SESSION variable.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use get method , and pass both Id of poster and ID of movie in your link,your link could be like this:Mywebsite.com/page2.php?movieId=321&posterId=1

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake now, I thought you had to use a <form> in order to use the get method, now I see it thanks!
This is how I solved it:
<a href="Page2.php?ID='.$row[id].'"><img src='.$row[poster].' /></a>

I spent another 15 minutes debugging because I pasted your link, using "Mywebsite" instead of the page I use, so yeah, it's THAT early...

Thanks! This question can be closed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get method , and pass both Id of poster and ID of movie in your link,your link could be like this:`Mywebsite.com/page2.php?movieId=321&posterId=1`.